# How can I get all numbers in each line in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm very lost at the moment, I have a document that have:

```
5632 Hello
545  Thing
6532 Have
```

and more... but I want to get all those number and put them like this:

[5632, 545, 6532] and then if I want to get more in dept information about that number, I pick the number and get the word

E.g: get 545 then get the word with it, which is Hello.

Also Sorry for my English, English isnt my first language.

Comment: So what have you done so far ?

Comment: Do you know about something called regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

example:

```
var numberRegex = /\d+/g;
var numbers = '5632 Hello 545 Thing 6532 Have'.match(numberRegex)
console.log(numbers)

// Output:
// ["5632", "545", "6532"]
```

in your case:

```
var arr= '5632 Hello 545 Thing 6532 Have'.match(/\d+ \w+/g)
var pairs= new Array()
arr.forEach(function(v) {
   pair = v.split(/\s/g);
   pairs.push({number: pair[0], name: pair[1]})
})

console.log('number:', pairs[0]['number'], 'name:',pairs[0]['name'])

// Output:
// number: 5632 name: Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to manipulate over the string and transform it into a proper array. Then, you can iterate over it by using `Array#forEach` and catch up all the elements you like.

```js
var str = "5632 Hello \n545  Thing \n6532 Have",
    arr = str.split('\n').map(v => v.trim().replace(/\s+/, ',').split(',')),
    numbers = [],
    names = [];
    
    arr.forEach(function(v) {
      numbers.push(v[0]);
      names.push(v[1]);
    });
    
    console.log(numbers, names);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions

Supposing we have may lines and each line contain two values separated by a space

```
var text = `5632 Hello
545 Thing
6532 Have`

var result = text.split('\n').map(function(element) {
    return element.split(' ')
}).reduce(function(obj, element) {
    obj[element[0]] = element[1];
    return obj;
}, {});
```

this code will return an object like this

```
{545: "Thing", 5632: "Hello", 6532: "Have"}
```